# How do I fix error of system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, error-handling

hello I'm having issues about setting up apps on my visual studio pro version. After get code is done then I click the app but the message pops up like Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. My framework is .NET Framework 4.5 and I downloaded MySQL connector 6.9.9 version. And I don't know whether my 64-bit version of windows 10 pro or the framework and MySQL connector have wrong settings.

The error message says :

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************

```
     System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
      at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
   at superpos3.Main.pictureBox2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
      D:\superpos3\superpos3\superpos3\Main.cs:line 22
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4180.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
superpos3
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///D:/superpos3/superpos3/superpos3/bin/Debug/superpos3.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4150.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4001.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4180.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
MySql.Data
    Assembly Version: 6.9.9.0
    Win32 Version: 6.9.9.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/MySql.Data/v4.0_6.9.9.0__c5687fc88969c44d/MySql.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4121.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

 <configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>
```

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

**I added here ok...**

main.cs, line 22 is just this code : System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Word");

When I click to my Microsoft word app on Main.cs[Design] form the error appeared. I think the error comes from MySQL connector 6.9.9 and framework 4.5.

I added the references like from assemblies these files of the MySQL connector net 6.9.9 folder:

```
Mysql.Data.dll
Mysql.Data.Entity.dll
MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll
Mysql.Fabric.Plugin.dll
Mysql.Web.dll
The codes in Main.cs is:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace superpos3
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Word");
        }

        private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Excel");
        }

        private void pictureBox4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("PowerPoint");
        }

        private void pictureBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Access");
        }

        private void pictureBox6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Windows is going to shut down. Are you sure?", "Please confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");

            }
        }

        private void pictureBox7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("NotePad");
        }

        private void pictureBox8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Calculator");
        }

        private void pictureBox11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Google Chrome");
        }

        private void pictureBox10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Internet Explorer");
        }

        private void pictureBox9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Windows is going to restart. Are you sure?", "Please confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/r /t 0");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So obviously a file is missing. What is cour code in Main.cs, line 22?

Comment: Please paste your code.

Comment: please see the below answer

Comment: Don't add it as answer, but [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Word executable is named "winword.exe", not "word.exe"

Answer (score 0):

main.cs, line 22 is just this code : System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Word");

When I click to my Microsoft word app on Main.cs[Design] form the error appeared.
I think the error comes from MySQL connector 6.9.9 and framework 4.5.

I added the references like from assemblies these files of the MySQL connector net 6.9.9 folder:

```
Mysql.Data.dll
Mysql.Data.Entity.dll
MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll
Mysql.Fabric.Plugin.dll
Mysql.Web.dll
```

The codes in Main.cs is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace superpos3
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Word");
        }

        private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Excel");
        }

        private void pictureBox4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("PowerPoint");
        }

        private void pictureBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Access");
        }

        private void pictureBox6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Windows is going to shut down. Are you sure?", "Please confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");

            }
        }

        private void pictureBox7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("NotePad");
        }

        private void pictureBox8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Calculator");
        }

        private void pictureBox11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Google Chrome");
        }

        private void pictureBox10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Internet Explorer");
        }

        private void pictureBox9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Windows is going to restart. Are you sure?", "Please confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/r /t 0");

            }
        }
    }
}
```